# Computed parameter in Modelica

Tags: parameters, modelica

I have a model in which one of the parameters should be found by solving a nonlinear equation. Is it possible to implement one such case in Modelica? For example:

```
parameter Real Rs
```

should be found by solving the equation:

```
(VmaxP*(Isc+I0_diode-2*ImaxP)-ImaxP*I0_diode*Rs)/(VmaxP-Rs*ImaxP)+I0_diode*exp((VmaxP+Rs*ImaxP)/(a*Ns*Vth_diode))*((Rs*(ImaxP-Isc)+VmaxP-a*Ns*Vth_diode)/(a*Ns*Vth_diode))=0;
```

in the above nonlinear equation, only `Rs` is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters can be computed in the initial equation section when they are declared with `fixed=false`. Just put your nonlinear equation into this section and `Rs` will be computed if all other variables are known.

```
model FixedFalse

  parameter Real Rs(fixed=false);

  // dummy values to let the model simulate
  Real VmaxP=1; Real Isc=1; Real I0_diode=1;
  Real ImaxP=1; Real a = 1; Real Ns = 1; Real Vth_diode = 1;

initial equation 

  (VmaxP*(Isc+I0_diode-2*ImaxP)-ImaxP*I0_diode*Rs)/(VmaxP-Rs*ImaxP)+I0_diode*exp((VmaxP+Rs*ImaxP)/(a*Ns*Vth_diode))*((Rs*(ImaxP-Isc)+VmaxP-a*Ns*Vth_diode)/(a*Ns*Vth_diode))=0;

end FixedFalse;
```

To prevent that this parameter is shown in the parameter dialog, you can protect it and add a non-final parameter, e.g. for plotting:

```
  ...

  final parameter Real Rs = _Rs;

protected 
  parameter Real _Rs(fixed=false);

initial equation 
  // Now use _Rs here
  ...
```